# What is the output of IFFT operations, continuous or discrete time?

Tags: digital-communications

Assume we have a sequence of symbols 
$$S= \{0, 0, 1+j, -1-j, 0 ,0 , 1+j,-1+j\}$$

and that this sequence is a frequency domain sequence and will be input to an IFFT operation.

Is the output a *continous time* or *discrete time* signal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FFT is just a fast algorithm for evaluating the [discrete Fourier transform (DFT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform). The domains for the DFT are discrete in both time and frequency. So, the result of an inverse DFT using the inputs you showed above will be a discrete-time signal.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'S' sequence, comprising frequency-domain samples, is a "discrete-frequency signal". When you perform an IFFT on the 'S' sequence you'll generate a sequence of time-domain samples. Any time-domain sequence made up of a sequence of samples (a list of numbers) is a "discrete-time signal".

When you graphically draw a discrete-time signal (versus time) on a piece of paper, you must draw a sequence of dots.  In doing so your pencil tip will periodically leave the surface of the paper.  On the other hand, if you ever had to draw a "continuous signal" on paper, you'll draw a curved line where the tip of your pencil never leaves the surface of the paper.

Comment: my question is what is the output of ifft?

Comment: Tyrone, today I modified my original post hoping to make it more useful.